# Can't send crash report

Tags: kubuntu, bug-reporting, bugzilla

Where do I have to complain about bugs regarding the crash report system of Kubuntu 16.04?
Or does anyone know about this bug?

Background: a few days ago I tried to send a bug report, wich Kubuntu offered me to do (HDMI-problems), but I got this Error message:

[image: Screenshot of Error sending bug report]

Unfortunately I can't provide any other useful information, except the Screenshot.

Comment: There is a text: " The version value '5.5.5' is not active". It might be that your component is too old. It is not supported and the bug report is not accepted. By example, if I open the kwin bug report in the KDE bug tracker the accepted versions will began from the 5.8.7. Current plasma version is 5.12.3.